# Can I update my nvidia drivers after installing CUDA and CUDNN without messing up with my CUDA installation?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia, linux-mint, cudnn

I want to update my nvidia drivers from 375 to the latest one on my linux mint 18.1 because I'm having screen corruption after resume from suspend. But I have already installed CUDA Toolkit and CUDNN. Is it possible to directly update with no problem or do I have to reinstall everything again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can download just the driver from this [link](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx).

Comment: would updating my drivers mess up with my cuda installation?

Comment: @RohitGajawada no

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just solved it by following this gist: [install NVIDIA driver](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07)

If you have already installed CUDA and CUDnn, that means you have the run (or deb) file for CUDA and the not-so-heavy cudnn source files too. Following the above link, you might have to purge your current cuda installation for a while, but it can be easily installed once you have upgraded your NVIDIA drivers.

I highly recommend that you purge your current installation of CUDA before going ahead, as a lot of links are formed during the installation, which might be the cause of the screen corruption that you faced.